# how to validate the phone number in form field xml

Tags: php, validation, joomla, phone-number

how to check the phone number field in joomla

```
<field
        name="mobileno"
        type="tel"
        description="mobileno"
        label="Mobileno"
        pattern="[0-9]{10}" 
        required="true"
        size="30"  
    />
```

Comment: depending on your country phone number my have different form, maybe you should specify which country's phone number should pass the validation

Answer (score 3):

There are some ready made validations available including telephone validation. You just have to add `validate="tel"` in your xml file.

```
<field
        name="mobileno"
        type="tel"
        description="mobileno"
        label="Mobileno"
        validate="tel" 
        required="true"
        size="30"  
    />
```

Reference: [Validation rules](https://docs.joomla.org/Server-side_form_validation)

Comment: Thanks emmanuel , how to check mobile number pattern or digits,

Comment: The tel validation checks all phone numbers to see if the follow the ITU rules. There are a number of options you can use such as specifying a specific ITU format. You can see these in the file `/libraries/joomla/form/rule/tel.php`. There is also tel handling in the `filterField()` method of `JForm`  and output formatting in  `JHtml` which you might want to use.

Comment: thanks elin then , i want to check phone number starting from 7,8,9 and also it must be 10 digits like 9XXXXXXXXX, 7XXXXXXXXX, 8XXXXXXXXX